# I'd like to fix <div> during scrolling down

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to fix Green bar which is changed by Red bar even when I scroll down [this page](https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/slideup_like_magic/).

[image]

Then, I wrote HTML like following this and when I scroll down, the Green bar doesn't move and disappear.
Only texts, banana and lemon, are affixed as this photo.

[image]

I tried to write several `jQuery` codes and changed `CSS` like this,

```
div#foo {
    position: fixed;
}

div#bar {
    position: fixed;
}
```

but, it doesn't move as I want.
The bar is fixed, but not like [Affix function of Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp).
I know, the problem is my CSS part, especially `position`. I am sorry, but I am not familiar with CSS.
Would you please give me some adcvices?

```js
  $(function(){

   /**
    * affix.js
    */
   $('.lemon').affix({
    offset: {
          top: 100,
          bottom: 100
       }
     });

     /**
    * Fixing Header
    */
   /*$(window).on('load scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
     $('.lemon').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
     $('.lemon').css('position', 'absolute');
    }
   });*/

   /**
    * slideUp
    */
   // setTimeout(function() {
   //  $("div#foo").animate(
   //   {height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow", function() {
   //    $("div#bar").show();
   //  });
   // }, 2000);
  
   setTimeout(function(){
    $('div#foo').addClass('magictime slideUp');
   }, 5000);


   /**
    * the quantity of scroll
    */
   $(window).scroll(function () {
       var ScrTop = $(document).scrollTop();
       $('#intervalValue').val(ScrTop);
   });

  });
```

```css
  body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  fixed {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 10;
  }

  div#foo {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9999;
  }

  div#bar {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   /* display: none; */
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9998;
  }

  .magictime {
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-fill-mode: both;
  }

  .slideUp {
   animation-name: slideUp;
  }

  @keyframes slideUp {
   0% {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: translateY(0%);
   }
   100% {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
   }
  }

  h1 {
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: center;
  }

  div#interval {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 9999;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="" class="lemon">  <!-- Or data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" --> 
  <div id="foo" class="">Apple Orange</div>
  <div id="bar" class="">Banana Lemon</div>
 </div>
 <div id="listlist" class="">
  <ul>
   <li>HTML</li>
   <li>CSS</li>
   <li>JavaScript</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) :)

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry. It's difficult to see my photos, right? And it seems my Keyboard doesn't have `PrtScn` key...sorry. But thank you for your advice.

Comment: @yamachan Well, just look on your keyboard and seach the key with this border between these 2 words. You normaly will have 2, just take the first.

Comment: @PatrickMlr Thank you for your comment. My keyboard is this, `http://www.pfu.fujitsu.com/hhkeyboard/lite2/images/pdkb220b_l.jpg`. Simplified one. Is there the key on mine?

Comment: @yamachan Looks like you don't have this key. Just use the "Snipping Tool" if you have Windows

Comment: @PatrickMlr Thank you for your advice. I didn't know about `Snipping Tool`. I will use this tool instead from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this div:

```
<div id="" class="lemon">
```

Give it a ID and try to give it a CSS-Style with jQuery when you scroll down.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="lemon">
```

Example jQuery:

```
$("#menu").css("position", "fixed");
$("#menu").css("width", "100%");
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Patric Mlr. I added your code, `$("#menu").css("width", "100%");` in `Fixing Header` part of my `jQuery`. And it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @yamachan If this answer helped you and you want to share this, accept this answer please.

Comment: @yamachan I don't see how you can accept this as an answer. What you are doing here is to add inline css with jQuery instead of just changing your already existing css rule. Just so you know, jQuery is much slower the pure css. What I mean is that it is better to have a god css foundation and make all styling in the css if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is to change position: absolut to fixt for #bar like this:

```
    div#bar {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        /* display: none; */
        position: fixed;  <--- here is the change
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9998;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Zorken17. It worked. I never thought `position: fixed` only at `div#bar`. Thank you.